# error in C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

here are my two functions:

```
 public void SetCompanies()
    //set the Companies table from Shret.net DataBase
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://api.sherut.net/?method=Company");
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);

            try
            {
                webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = null;
            var companies = (Companies)serializer.ReadObject(e.Result);
            foreach (Company c in companies.data)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(c.Name + " " + c.CompanyID);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the error i get:

> "No overload for 'webClient_OpenReadCompleted' matches delegate
>   'System.Net.OpenReadCompletedEventHandler'"

i dont understand why, because i wrote the handler after this function......
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`OpenReadCompleted` doesn't take `OpenWriteCompletedEventArgs`.